# how to query the result of fn:analyze-string()?

Tags: xquery, saxon, basex

In XQuery (in BaseX which uses Saxon 10.something as well as in XSLT with Saxon 9.9.1.7 within Oxygen), I tried to iterate the matches of *fn:analyze-string()* by
`fn:analyze-string($term, $pattern)/match` which did not give me any output although the function itself returned the typical element with <match> and <non-match> childnodes. According to the definition, the function returns "[...] an XML structure [...]" ([cf.](https://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions/)). Hence, one should be able to query it like that and the given expression should work.

Since it did not, I then tried `fn:analyze-string($term, $pattern)/*[fn:local-name(.) eq 'match']`...and it worked. Replacing the asterisk and the condition in the brackets with `child::match` etc. didn't, however.

My question is: Why? What is the difference; what did I miss here? In all cases, the child nodes are queried by the name *match*. So, why does only the version with the asterisk get me the results?

Comment: BaseX uses its own implementation of XQuery. It may (I'm not sure) use Saxon for XSLT transformations invoked by fn:transform(), but it certainly doesn't use it for core XQuery functionality.

Comment: @MichaelKay right, BaseX uses its own implementation and adresses Saxon for xsl:transform(). I updated the question since I ran into the same problem in XSLT that is processed by Saxon.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `match` elements are in a namespace, specifically the "fn" namespace (`http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions`). So the unqualified name test `match` won't find them unless this happens to be the default namespace for elements (which won't be the case by default). You should match them using `fn:match` (where `fn` is bound to the right namespace), or `*:match`.

This question is probably the most commonly asked question on StackOverflow about XSLT, XPath, and XQuery. However, because it's asked in so many different ways and the symptoms vary so widely, it's hard to close it as a duplicate. But if you search for "XPath default namespace" you'll find thousands of other users (2137 at the last count) falling into the same error.

Comment: Thank you! I was thinking of something about the namespace already but still wondered why because it's the default namespace for functions. In BaseX as well as in Saxon, its prefix is not mandatory - except in some cases as I now know.